# Communication between PHP (Zend) and the database

Tags: database, sockets, zend-framework

I'm trying to understand how actually the communication between Zend framework and the database works (but it's not so easy as it seems ;) ).

My main focus is on  [Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Socket](http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/Http/Client/Adapter/Socket.php) class, especially read() function. In some magical way it receives the response from the database and sets the status of the answer. However I cannot spot where is the actual data processing done. What if I want to control the code returned by the database? F.e. I want database to return 204 in some special cases depending on data. Where can it be done?
I see that sockets enable communication by waiting for each other requests/responses. But Where is it exactly done on the part of the database?

Comment: Why are you concentrating on Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Socket and not Zend_Db_adapter? Are you working with distributed databases or something else unique?

Comment: No, I'm just learning and testing different functions to try to understand how they work.

Comment: You should to look at(learn) TDG design patterns for totally understand ...

Answer (score 3):

I think you should concentrate more on the Zend_Dd_Adapter as RockyFord mentioned in the comment section.
When i am working with the ZF my model comes in 2 parts. An object where the data from the database is holded in and a mapper that has the methods save, edit, delete, find and many more. 
So the Mapper is initialising a new Zend_Db_Table_Abstract. Example:

```
class Application_Model_DbTable_Cable extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = "cable";
    protected $_primary = "ID";
}
```

The instance of Zend_Db_Table_Abstract should you store in your mapper and than you can call for example:

```
$this->dbTable->find($id);
```

For more information have a look at the Reference Guide of the ZF: [Zend_Db](http://www.framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.html)

Or ask it here :)

Answer (score 2):

> Where can it be done? I see that sockets enable communication by
>   waiting for each other requests/responses. But Where is it exactly
>   done on the part of the database?

Your questions really don't apply to `Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Socket` as it relates to a database.

`Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Socket` deals with an *http* connection request/response cycle.

All of the database adapters in Zend Framework are primarily wrappers (*emulate and/or extend the function*) for the PHP extensions. (PHP extensions are registered in the php.ini file and have the format of `extension=extension_name`)

Most of us are currently using the PDO extension for our favorite variety of database.

So to really answer your questions you'll need to dig into the creation of a database adapter for PHP. You might start with http://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.pdo.php if you are really curious.

However you can code a controller to return a response through  `Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Socket` based on the results of a database query.